# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Tags: angular, typescript

Please can you tell me how I solve this problem?

problem in browser:

```
core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
    at BookItemComponent_Template (book-item.component.html:4)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9599)
    at refreshView (core.js:9465)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10636)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9261)
    at refreshView (core.js:9515)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10636)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9261)
    at refreshView (core.js:9515)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:9579)
```

book.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Book } from './book.model';
    import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class BookService {
    
      url:string="http://localhost:31451/api/books"
      
      books:Book[];
      book:Book;
     
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
      getAllbooks (){
        this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(
          res=>{
            this.books =res as Book[];
          }
        )
      }
      postbook(){
        return  this.http.post(this.url, this.book); 
        
       // {headers: new HttpHeaders({'content-type':'application/json'})}
        
      
      }
    }
```

book.model.ts:

```
export class Book {
    id:number;
    title:string;
    author:string;
    numberOfPages:number;
    publishedAt:Date;
}
```

book-item.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BookService } from '../book.service';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-book-item',
      templateUrl: './book-item.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./book-item.component.css']
    })
    export class BookItemComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(public service:BookService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
    
      submit() {
            this.service.postbook().subscribe(res=>{
            this.service.getAllbooks()
               },
        err=>{
          console.log(err)
       })
   }}
```

book-item.component.html:

form to add data

```
 <form  ngForm="form" (submit)="submit()"  >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.book.title"  name="title" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Author">Author:</label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.book.author"  name="author" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="numberOfPages">Number Of Pages:</label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.book.numberOfPages" name="numberOfPages" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="publishedAt">published At:</label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.book.publishedAt" name="publishedAt" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" value="save book" >
            </form>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `serive.book` property is `undefined` because it doesn't have an initial value. So in your service, just initialize the `book` property like the following:

```js
book: Book = new Book();
```

Comment: thanks a lot its working But this problem appears to me (:31451/api/books:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request))

Comment: This error comes from your server, check the expected request body, or query strings to know where is the problem exactly.

Comment: in the same project I have to way get and post , get its working but when I post data from form to database this problem appears to me ? Please can you tell me how I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to check the endpoint expected parameters and if they are identical with your request parameters or not. Good luck!

Comment: you can check all properties inside input tag like this *ngIf="service.book.title"

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your form in an *ngIf as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="service.book">

  <form ... etc>

</ng-container>
```

Or use the operator:

```
[(ngModel)]="service.book?.title"
```

And do same with author, etc

Comment: In the first method, the table disappears, but in the second method, it does not work

Comment: it means service.book is not set - the table would appear if it was set

Answer (score 0):

My almost exact same error was:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'background_image')`

I figured out that my.component.html was rendering faster than the promise/subscription in my.component.ts was returning. Since the parent of "background_image", "game" is an object, I tested for typeof 'object' before rendering the html like this:

In my.component.ts, I added this function:

```js
isObject(value: any): boolean { return typeof value === 'object'; }
```

In my.components.html, I added this *ngIf statement wrapper around all my html code:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isObject(game)">
  <div>
      ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

- if your 'undefined' value is a 'string', 'number', 'boolean, etc, you can use the same function just change what typeof it looks for.
- My reasoning behind this tactic is, globals like window, typeof, enums, or static methods are not available within a template. Only members of the component class and typescript language constructs are available.